# div content not hiding when anchor tag is clicked using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having issues with a navigation bar. When on mobile, I want the content of the navigation bar to be hidden once a list item is clicked. The issue only occurs when you resize the window from large to small; it doesn't occur when the screen size is already small. So you have to click on "expand snippet" to see the issue. I think there's something wrong with my javaScript code, but i'm not sure what it is. Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var menuStatus = true;
  var sections = $('section');
  var nav = $('nav');
  //smooth scroll
  $("nav,#arrow").find('a').on('click', function() {
    var el = $(this),
      id = el.attr('href');

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(id).offset().top
    }, 500);
  });

  //hide the mobile nav after a link is clicked
  if ($(window).width() < 900) {
    $("nav li a").on('click', function() {
      $(".menu").hide();
      $('nav input:checkbox:checked').prop('checked', false);
    });

    $("nav input").on('click', function() {
      $(".menu").show();
    });
  }

  //show desktop nav when the screen is at least 900px
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    var win = $(this);
    if (win.width() > 900) {
      $(".menu").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

nav img {
  height: 150px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav__container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 110%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Rajdhani', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #5f3917;
  background-color: #fbd802;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.active {
  color: #1CAB1D;
}

nav .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

nav .menu-icon {
  margin-top: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


/*close icon*/

nav .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #b32025;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: background .2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background .2s ease-out;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}


/*menu icon bottom and top lines*/

nav .menu-icon .navicon:before,
nav .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #b32025;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

nav .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

nav .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}


/* menu btn */

nav .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}


/*height of vertical menu*/

nav .menu-btn:checked~.menu {
  max-height: 300px;
}

nav .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}


/*when clicked animate*/

nav .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}


/*when clicked animate*/

nav .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

nav .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
nav .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}


/* MEDIA QUERIES */

@media only screen and (max-width: 730px) {
  nav li:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(252, 65, 65, 0.2);
  }
  nav ul {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .nav__wrapper {
    display: inline;
  }
  .container {
    padding: 100px 20px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 730px) {
  nav {
    background-color: #fbd802;
  }
  nav img {
    height: 70px;
  }
  nav li:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(252, 65, 65, 0.2);
  }
  nav ul {
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav li {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .nav__container {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 730px) {
  ul {
    display: flex;
  }
  nav .menu {
    max-height: none;
  }
  nav .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}

.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 100px 40px;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
}

#home {
  background: red;
}

#aboutUs {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="home">
    <nav>
      <div class="nav__container">
        <img id="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="logo">
        <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
        <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="#aboutUs">about us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#menu">menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#gallery">gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </section>

  <section id="aboutUs">

  </section>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following error running your script: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`.

There are 2 ways to fix this. Either add all the elements listing in the href's and not just `#aboutUs`, or change your JS to the following:

```
$("nav,#arrow").find('a').on('click', function() {
    var elm_id = $(this).attr('href');
    var section = $(elm_id);

    if(section.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: section.offset().top
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

-- EDIT --

Full Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // smooth scroll
    $("nav, #arrow").on('click', 'a', function() {
        var elm_id = $(this).attr('href');
        var section = $(elm_id);

        if(section.length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: section.offset().top
            }, 500);
        }
    });

    // Handle Mobile Menu
    var $window = $(window);
    var $menu = $(".menu");
    $("nav li a").on('click', function() {
        if ($window.width() < 900) {
            $menu.hide();
            $('nav input:checkbox:checked').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
    $("nav input").on('click', function() {
        if ($window.width() < 900) {
            $menu.show();
        }
    });
    // show desktop nav when the screen is at least 900px
    $window.on('resize', function() {
        if ($window.width() > 900) {
            $menu.show();
        } else {
            $menu.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't fix it. That code is just for the smooth scroll.

Comment: You were absolutely right. The problem was you were locking the link clicks behind an if statement that only registered them if the pages was loaded in the mobile version.

Comment: Thanks Trevor! This worked, but it introduced a new issue. Now when you resize the window, the nav changes to display:block.

Comment: Change `$menu.show();` to  `$menu.css('display','flex');` in the window resize area.

Comment: You should also change `nav .menu-icon { display: none; }` into a media query for greater than 900px. Right now you don't see a menu for anything from 730px to 900px

Comment: For some reason  `$menu.css('display','flex');` in the window resize area, also makes the nav flex when on mobile size.

Comment: I would change `$menu.show();` to `$menu.css('display','block');` in the `$("nav input").on('click', function() {` section.

Comment: Another tip after playing with the page to make sure there is nothing else: add `$('nav input:checkbox:checked').prop('checked', false);` below `$menu.hide();` in the `$window.on('resize', function() {` section for people who will be resizing the browser.